# Javascript How to create an alias for 'scope' of namespaced objects

Tags: javascript

I have a namespaced object

```
    ONE.TWO.THREE = {
    my_var:'', 
    myfunction : function () {
      my_var = 1;                //does not work >> undefined
      ONE.TWO.THREE.my_var = 1 ; // works fine but it is a lot of code
    }  
  ...... }
```

'This' does not work ( window...) so I have to create or use a 'scope' or 'self' var. But in this case I can't (or I dont know how to).,

By now I have to use ONE.TWO.THREE.my_var ....
Is it possible to create some kind of alias ?

Is there any trick ? Have I to change to module pattern ?  Thanks.

Comment: And using `this.myVar = 1;`?

Comment: @Niels'This' does not work (= window). I'm calling ONE.TWO.THREE.myfunction from setTimeot funcs & eventlistener addings. Maybe this way can be the problem ? By now I'm think i'm going to use a temp alias....

Comment: When you send the function to `setTimeout` you can either use `bind` (`setTimeout(ONE.TWO.THREE.myfunction.bind(ONE.TWO.THREE), 1000);`) or wrap your function in an anonymous function (`setTimeout(function () { ONE.TWO.THREE.myfunction(); }, 1000);`). Both of those solution will ensure that the right context is preserved, so that you safely can use `this.my_var = 1;`.

Comment: Thanks everyboby. The solution is not clear either usefull .... By now i'm going to keep a full namespace style ....

Comment: @civiltomain: Is there some issue with using `this`?

Answer (score 3):

You have the following options:

```
ONE.TWO.THREE = {
   my_var : 0,
   fn : function(){ this.my_var = 10; }
};
ONE.TWO.THREE.fn(); // Will se ONE.TWO.THREE.my_var to 10 
                    // because the this will referr to the object
```

Or make a temp variable reffer to the object

```
var XX = {
  YY : {
     my : 0,
     fn : function(){
         var tmp = XX.YY; // Save the var to a temp var.
         tmp.my = 10;
     }
  }
}

XX.YY.fn() // Set to 10
XX.YY.my // Will be 10
```

Comment: What's the point of the `tmp` variable? `XX.YY.my = 10` would do the same thing.

Comment: In this example, yet. But if you want to reuse that variable like 10 times, you only need to define that temp once. Instead of writing the complete structure all the time.

Answer (score 0):

> Have I to change to module pattern ?

You don't have to, but if you don't want to use `this` (comments under the question suggest you don't), that might be the clearest, simplest way:

```
ONE.TWO.THREE = function() {
    var three = {
        my_var: '',
        myfunction: function() {
            three.my_var = 1;
        }
    };
    return three;
}();
```

Comment: mm yes  ... Sometimes it is difficult to find the pattern / style to use .... Object literal , prototype , module ....  Thanks any way

Comment: @civiltomain: Psychological studies show that the more choices you consider, the *less* happy you're likely to be with the choice you make. Odd, but true...